# Абсолютное позиционирование с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как спозиционировать элемент, относительно центра элемента стоящего перед ним. Ширина позиционируемого блока резиновая.

Вот [что сделал](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/eaKSQ/3/) я (пытался сделать).
Элемент `span`, вложенный в `p.prompt` - это стрелка, которую необходимо спозиционировать по центру `p.prompt`.

Данный код должен быть применим к любому блоку, в не зависимости от расположения на странице.

**[Вот графический фаил](http://крепежстрой.рф/form/image.jpg)** того, что должно получиться.

Необходимо сделать не всплывающую подсказку, а постоянную.

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь. Спасибо

Comment: @Alex83, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. Не совсем понятно, какова конечная цель, что необходимо получить. Создайте, допустим, иллюстративное представление

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элемент (назовем его подсказка) должен быть вложен в тот, на который нужно указать (назовем его контейнер). У контейнера должно быть свойство position: relative;. Подсказка должна быть position: absolute; bottom: -сколько нужно px; left: 50%; margin-left: - ширина подсказки px. Margin-left у подсказки нужно будет вычислять с помощью jquery, все остальные свойства в принципе тоже можно задавать с помощью jquery, но лучше прописать через css

Comment: @Андрей Советкин, спасибо. Согласен, но это решение требует подгонки под каждый отдельный случай, а хотелось бы найти универсальное решение.

Comment: @Alex83, с помощью jQuery после проверки вставлять такой элемент в тот, который необходимо указать? М?

Comment: @stck, не понял... Можно более подробно? И какие еще есть варианты, если не jQuery?

Comment: @Alex83, 

 - Я имел ввиду "подгонки под каждый отдельный случай" не надо. Вы же в любом случае проверяете поле на правильность/валидность - не важно. Так вот. Если вы это делаете на сервере - выводите в JS массив идентификаторов элементов, которые необходимо пометить такими метками + сообщения прилагаемые. А если на клиенте - то проверка полей JS и если ошибка - вставляем этот блок с элементом внутрь Вашего не валидного поля.
 - JS обычный. Но если проверяете на сервере и генерируете поля динамически, то проверяйте условия при повторной генерации и вставляйте заданный шаблон внутрь элемента.

Comment: А почему под каждый случай? margin-left вычисляется для каждой подсказки индивидуально  соответственно она встанет по середине, отступ от других элементов можно задать родителю вычислив высоту подсказки - опять же через jquery

Comment: @Alex83, если не сильны в JS - тут 2 выхода:
1) Учить JS
2) Не учить JS и не использовать его, а выводить по-простому как-нибудь:) Всё придёт с опытом - лучше эффективность чем красивость

Comment: @stck, Спасибо за совет. Согласен - учиться,учиться и еще раз учиться. Удачи.